# CodeIgniter How to create Multiple Site with One CMS

Tags: codeigniter, content-management-system

I want to create a blog site with only one CMS. This CMS will be in different domain.

For example: mycms.com

Then my blog sites are also in different domains.

For example: website1.com, website2.com, website3.com

They will all use mycms.com as their admin

*Images will be uploaded in mycms.com/images/ so all the 3 websites will get the images from this directory

If images are loaded on website1.com from the main database, they should be displayed as if they're from website1.com. So for example website1.com/images/cat.jpg instead of mycms.com/images/cat.jpg

How will I build this using codeigniter?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the same CodeIgniter /System and /Application folders for all the websites if you like;  just make sure all the `index.php` files are setup to use those same folders for `$system_path` and `$application_folder` respectively. Note that these sites also need to reside on the same server.

You can serve up different content by checking `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` for the domain the request came from.

As for htaccess you should be able to use `%{HTTP_HOST}/$1` or `%{HTTP_HOST}$1` (depending on server config) to make the rewrite rule dynamic.

I am actually building a similar project right now using CodeIgniter but there are also [several other projects available](http://www.google.com/search?q=codeigniter+cms+multisite) like halogy, codefight, pyro (with an extension), and many others.

Answer (score 1):

CodeIgniter has a System and an Application folder. You could have one global system folder and then one application folder for each of your subdomains, or you could have one application folder and just make your subdomian folders parallel with your www folder.

Comment: Ok got an idea..But what will I do to my htaccess so that the URL in the rewrite rule will be dynamic?

For example:

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://this-domain-should-be-dynamic.com/$1 [L,R=301]

Comment: You can't do that in your htaccess - you'll need to set that up in your vhosts. Check out http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_vhost_alias.html as well.